# Add JBoss Server Runtime Environment to Eclipse Mars

Tags: eclipse, jboss, eclipse-mars

I try to add the my JBoss AS 7.1 "Server Runtime Environment" to my new installed eclipse mars.

But under Server > Runtime Environment there is no Jboss server to select! Also in "Download additional server adapters" is no jboss to choose...

[image: New Server Runtime Environment without jboss]

I already installed the JBoss Tools 4.3.0.Beta2 but with no effect.

Do i something wrong or is there a bug in eclipse?

My eclipse version:

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Mars Release (4.5.0)
Build id: 20150621-1200

Comment: Ok, i found the problem. I was using java 1.7 but the JBoss Tools needs the version 1.8. Now it works....

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you are using JDK 1.8 with your Eclipse. This is because JBOSS Tools 4.3.0 Beta 2 needs a JDK version of at least 1.8 to work.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who would encounter the same problem: Make sure to have JDK 1.8

Open Eclipse > Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs (Use JRE 1.8)

Then proceed to Window > Preferences > Server > Runtime Environments > Add

There you can see the other runtime environment appears :)